# How would I print out a string one letter at a time using Python Curses?

Tags: python, python-curses

For some style in my console applications, I'll often have a string print out one character at at time using code like this:

```
import time


def run():
    the_string = "Hello world!"
    for char in the_string:
        print(char, end='', flush=True)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    input()


run()
```

I am looking to do the same with Python Curses, so I can have some more flexibility in other aspects of the application.  This is what I have so far:

```
import curses
import time


def run(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    the_string = "Hello world!"
    for char in the_string:
        stdscr.addstr(char)
        time.sleep(0.1)
    stdscr.getch()


curses.wrapper(run)
```

problem is this just waits for the duration of the for loop before putting the text on the console.  The difference is `flush=True` so I've tried to include `curses.flushinp()` at a few different places in the function, but it makes no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to call the [`stdscr.refresh()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/curses.html#curses.window.refresh) after writing the string to the screen to refresh the screen.

```
import curses
import time


def run(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    the_string = "Hello world!"
    for char in the_string:
        stdscr.addstr(char)
        stdscr.refresh()
        time.sleep(0.1)
    stdscr.getch()


curses.wrapper(run)
```

works fine as you intended.